# User Registration in android with php integration and Threads

Tags: java, php, android

I have a problem with my code and can't figure out what's wrong 
I am trying to make a registration form and submit the username and password to the database
The username and password and successfully stored in the database but the problem is that I am not able to test whether they were inserted or not.
I have a response tester

```
if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

            dialog.dismiss();
                showAlert();    
        }
```

but the problem is that the `dialog.dismiss();` is executed while the `showAlert();` is not executed

This is my full code for the `RegisterActivity.java`

```
Button b;
EditText et,pass;
TextView tv;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterActivity.this, "", 
                    "Validating user...", true);

             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Register();
                    }
                  }).start();               
        }
    });

}

void Register(){
    try{            

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.112/RegisterConnectNow.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);


        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

            dialog.dismiss();
                showAlert();    
        }else {
            dialog.dismiss();
            showAlert();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
public void showAlert(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("OK")
    .setMessage("OK")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // continue with delete
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // do nothing
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
     .show();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.register, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void displayToast(String s){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and this is the php script

`DatabaseConnectNow.php`

```
    <?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="users";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
?>
```

`RegisterConnectNow.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'DatabaseConnectNow.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query_search = "select * from userstable where username = '".$username."'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);

 if($rows == 0) { 
 $query = "INSERT INTO userstable (username,password)
                    VALUES ('$username', '$password')";

            mysql_query($query);

            echo "1";
 }
 else  {
    echo "2"; 
}
?>
```

So I am testing if the response is 1 then It should display the dialog , I tried displaying a toast and its the same thing nothing gets displayed, I have a feeling this have to do with the threads.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new Runnable for the AlertDialog box in order to show it right after the progress dialog box. you can do is something like this:

on your `public void showAlert()` do this:

```
public void showAlert(){

    YourActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this)
                    .setTitle("OK")
                    .setMessage("OK")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // continue with delete
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JLONG I tried this before asking here and it didn't work but your code worked. Been trying to solve it for a whole day.